# Change a row in a CSV with Python by key data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, edit

So I'm trying to create a function where the user will input a unique identifier (a number in this case in the first column) so they can then edit the details in that row in a CSV. I'm getting close, but rather than editing, or at least, deleting the original and putting a new row in, it's just adding it to the end. Any help greatly appreciated. Popped what I have so far below, I may well be barking up the completely wrong virtual tree....

```
reference = "2"

fi = open('mylovelycsv.csv', 'r')
calls = []
while True:
    call = fi.readline()
    if not call:
        break
    fields = call.split(',')
    calls.append(call)
    if fields[0] == reference:
        fields[1] = "This is a new bit of information"
        new_details = ','.join(fields)
calls.append(new_details)
fi.close()

fo = open('mylovelycsv.csv', 'w')
for row in calls:
    fo.write(row)
fo.close()
```

Idea of the CSV...

```
1, blue, to go to the moon
2, orange, to swim with dolphins
3, black, to have a big house and lots of money
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using append as that, well, appends to the end of the list.

You want to replace an existing item in the list and you can do that directly by referring to it by it's index.

That's what the code below does but there are probably better ways

```py
reference = "2"
idx = 0 
fi = open('test.csv', 'r')
calls = []
while True:
    call = fi.readline()

    if not call:
        break
    calls.append(call)
    
    fields = call.split(',')
    if fields[0] == reference:
        fields[1] = "This is a new bit of information"
        new_details = ','.join(fields)
        calls[idx] = new_details
    idx+=1
fi.close()

fo = open('mylovelycsv.csv', 'w')
for row in calls:
    fo.write(row)
fo.close()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help